# Confusion about example of Lebesgue measurable set that is not Borel

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-sets

I have a question regarding the example of a set that is Lebesgue measurable, but not a Borel set on $\mathbb{R}$ given in https://www.math3ma.com/blog/lebesgue-but-not-borel.
Wouldn't it be the case that we have $N = f(f^{-1}(N)) = (f^{-1})^{-1}(f^{-1}(N))$ measurable following this analysis? We namely have that $f^{-1}$ is continuous, hence measurable and the inverse mappings of Lebesgue measurable sets under $f^{-1}$ are hence Lebesgue measurable..

Comment: The preimage of a measurable set under a continuous function need not be measurable.

Comment: Why? All continuous functions are Lebesgue measurable right?

Comment: Pre-images of *open* sets are measurable.

Comment: Ah, thanks, I see it now.

Answer (score 1):

Umberto P. answered it in the comments:

> The preimage of a measurable set under a continuous function need not be measurable. Pre-images of *open* sets are measurable.